# Asterisk Perl AGI won’t continue

Tags: perl, asterisk, agi

I can get the call running the AGI, but I am not able to continue running the `extensions.conf` dial plan while my Perl script runs its loop.

So I need away to run this AGI in the background when the call is dialed.

The part of my AGI that is screwing up:

```
{
    my $linestatus = $agi->channel_status();

    ###THIS PART NEEDS TO LOOP UNTIL $linestatus == 6
    ###But It is also stopping the number from dialling.
    do{
    }
    until($linestatus == 6);

    my $query  = $collection->insert({
        caller     => $num,
        callername => $name,
        linestatus => $linestatus,
        extension  => $ext,
        call_start => $time }, {safe => 1});

    $agi->verbose("ANSWERED\n", 1);
}
```

My `extensions.conf` dial plan:

```
exten => _08.,1,AGI(bTel.agi)
exten => _08.,n,Dial(SIP/61${EXTEN:1}@SIPINTERNAL,,tTor)
exten => _08.,n,Hungup
```

Answer (score 3):

If

```
do{
}
until($linestatus == 6);
```

is a verbatim copy of your code, then the loop cannot terminate if `$linestatus` begins in the wrong state because its value does not change within the loop.

Instead, use code along the lines of

```
my $linestatus;
do {
    $linestatus = $agi->channel_status();
    sleep 1;  # or some other delay
} until (defined $linestatus && $linestatus == 6);
```

Comment: Also you need add in loop check for "(! defined $linestatus) ", becuase it will be undefined if loose connection with asterisk.